# How to clone column values in spark with their original order

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to clone the values of a column n times as they are in their original order.
For example if I want to replicate below column 2 times:

```
+---+
| v |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
```

What I am looking for :

```
+---+
| v |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
```

Using explode or flatMap I can only get :

```
+---+
| v |
+---+
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
+---+
```

Code:

```
%spark
val ds = spark.range(1, 4)
val cloneCount = 2

val clonedDs = ds.flatMap(r => Seq.fill(cloneCount)(r))
clonedDs.show()
```

I can probably do a self union of the dataset ds but if the cloneCount is huge, eg. cloneCount = 200000, is it a preferred solution to union in a loop that many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```scala
// If the column values are expected to be in an increasing/descresing sequence
// then we add that to the orderBy: clone_index and col_value
// to get the values in order as they were initially

val clonedDs = ds.flatMap(col_value => Range(0, cloneCount)
                   .map(clone_index=>(clone_index,col_value)) )
clonedDs.orderBy("_1", "_2").map(_._2).show()



// If the column values are not expected to follow a sequence
// then we add another rank column and use that in orderBy along with clone_index
// to get the col_values in desired order

val clonedDs = ds.withColumn("rank", monotonically_increasing_id())
    .flatMap(row => Range(0, cloneCount).map(
                clone_index=> (clone_index, row.getLong(1), row.getLong(0))
          ) )

clonedDs.orderBy("_1", "_2").map(_._3).show()
```

Comment: Hi Lokesh, Thanks for the quick response. But the order is still not preserved.

    val ds = spark.range(1, 4)
    val cloneCount = 6
    val clonedDs = ds.flatMap(r => Range(0, cloneCount).map(x=>(x,r)) )
    clonedDs.orderBy("_1").map(_._2).show()

Output :
  +-----+
  |value|
  +-----+
  |    1|
  |    2|
  |    3|
  |    2|
  |    3|
  |    1|
  |    1|
  |    2|
  |    3|
  |    1|
  |    2|
  |    3|
  |    2|
  |    3|
  |    1|
  |    1|
  |    2|
  |    3|
  +-----+

Comment: Yeah, that can happen. Didn't realize earlier, I just tried in local mode.
In case your column values are expected in be in order, then you can add that column as well to the orderBy. That should fix it.
`clonedDs.orderBy("_1", "_2").map(_._2).show()`

Comment: otherwise instead of column value, we can add a rank column to the data and then do a order by clone_index and rank. I am adding that to the answer

Comment: Got it, or I can sort the column before cloning it. I am always expecting the values to be numeric. It's just that the number of values in the column and cloneCount can both be huge.

Comment: Sorting the column before would not guarantee the order after ordering by clone_index. We need to order by column values after adding the clone_index. check my updated answer.

Comment: Yup, realized that after commenting. :)